# inverse.predict for $lmer$ models in R

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, predictive-models

In $lm$ models in R it is possible to use inverse.predict for predicting input value given a output value. But I can't find code making it for $lmer$ models. Do there not exists code for that in R?

Comment: Can you please add the corresponding working code for `lm()`, for exactly this situation with two features and one interaction?

Answer (score 1):

You can compute this manually.

The function inverts $$y = a+bx$$ to $$x = \frac{y-a}{b}$$ if you insert the estimates $a$ and $b$, then you get your answer.

For prediction intervals you need to do a bit extra work. I am not sure what approach the `inverse.predict` uses, but you could approximate the intervals based on an approximation of the distribution with a normal distribution.

---

You should be aware that this inversion may not generate good intervals when the correlation is low. See the example below where predictions and prediction intervals for two types of regression are shown.

The black lines relate to 'y ~ x' and it shows with broken lines the prediction of y given x.  The blue lines relate to 'x ~ y' and it shows with broken lines the prediction of x given y.

The `inverse.predict` function seems to relate to an inverse of the first (black) prediction boundaries and is depicted in red in the figure. (It is slightly different since it estimates in some way a standard error instead of using the true asymmetric boundaries)

In this figure the prediction boundaries from the inverse.predict function do not seem to perform well and result in a very large interval. (The reason is that the prediction conditions on the true value of x. Say that the true value is x=10, then the interval needs to work 95% of the time)

[image: example of bad performance for inverse.predict]

```
set.seed(1)
library(chemCal)
library(MASS)


### create data with a multivariate normal distribution 
m = mvrnorm(500, c(0,0), matrix(c(1,0.4,0.4,1),2))
x = m[,1]
y = m[,2]

### plot data
plot(x,y, xlim = c(-10,10),ylim=c(-10,10), cex=0.7)

### black lines 
### prediction and interval for y~x regression
mod = lm(y~x)
xs = seq(-17,17,0.1)
mp = predict(mod, newdata = list(x=xs,y=xs), interval = "prediction")
lines(xs, mp[,2], lty=2)
lines(xs, mp[,3], lty=2)
lines(xs, mp[,1],lwd=2)

### blue lines 
### prediction and interval for x~y regression
mod_inv = lm(x~y)
mp = predict(mod_inv, newdata = list(x=xs,y=xs), interval = "prediction")
lines( mp[,2], xs, lty=2, col = 4)
lines( mp[,3], xs, lty=2, col = 4)
lines( mp[,1],xs,lwd=2, lty=1, col = 4)


### red lines: example of inverse.predict interval if y=1.7
yp=1.7
lines(inverse.predict(mod, newdata = yp)$`Confidence Limits`,c(yp,yp), col =2, lwd =2)
points(inverse.predict(mod, newdata = yp)$`Confidence Limits`,c(yp,yp), pch = 21, col =2, bg="white", cex=1.3)
inverse.predict(mod, newdata = yp)
```

---

> But I have lmer function with interactions, so for example both $concentration+seconds+concentration*seconds$, so for example: $$lmer(y\sim concentration+seconds+concentration*seconds)$$.

This function is not invertible. You need a [bijective function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection#Inverses), whereas a function with multiple regressors like 'concentration' and 'seconds' maps different values to the same value of 'y'.

An exception is when you have a prior distribution for the values of the regressors, then you can "invert" the function in the sense of [inverse probability](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_probability) and computing a posterior.

Comment: This uses the overall mean of the random effects (ie zero) so the result will interpreted as being the average effect across all groups or levels in the random effects, which might be fine, but to implement this properly I would imagine we might want to offer an option to specify which group the potential observation comes from. +1 BTW :)

Comment: @RobertLong the inverse only works for a linear model with a single regressor.